# Bootstrap 3, putting a carousel within a carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Working with Bootstrap after a long time sure has been fun, but now I'm stuck on adding a slider/carousel within the TW Bootstrap 3 carousel, the styling doesn't matter as much right since at it's primarily about the functionality. I copied the CSS from my project (just the relevant bit) to the example.

In that JSFiddle you can see a little bit that I have thrown together, it doesn't show of to well but the main issue is when you move on to the next slide, the carousel within that carousel doesn't move to the correct location.

http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/4400/

Does anyone know how to fix this? I did an attempt with making the inner slider a BxSlider but it fails to load on the none-displaying slides. But I'd rather stay with Bootstrap instead of including other plugins.

Every carousel has its own `ID`, but they have equal classes, which I can imagine require some overwriting in Bootstraps core, but I haven't been able to find out how.. yet..

So basically, the issue is:
Bootstrap carousel that is within a Bootstrap carousel disappears when the parent carousel goes to another slide.

Comment: the second carousel is inside the first slide of the first carousel. if you want a carousel in the second slide then you either have to have a separate one

Comment: Erm, I'm not sure if I understand your comment. I duplicated the first slide 2 times so I'd have 3 slides in the main carousel. After that I change the identifiers of both embedded sliders so they would work independently.